# Command for c# to direct page

Tags: vb.net

how to make the code that check if there is no item in cart, the page will back on home page, `frmhome`. But if there is an item in cart, it will be directed to `frmincart`.

my code,

```
 Private Sub picMyCart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picMyCart.Click
    Me.Close()
    frmItemInCart.Show()
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: this is not c# code this seems to be vb.net

Comment: Is this web or desktop? you talk about home page, but your code indicates forms.

Comment: FAIL: Your question title doesn't match your question contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (itemInCart = True) Then
    frmItemInCart.Show() 'Or maybe: frmincart.Show() since you weren't clear about that, either...
Else
    frmhome.Show()
End If
```